# Why this component rerender again and again if i send props as a child in this component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

how to stop the rerendring of this component,is it posible or not

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

import CustomImageBackground from '../../components/ImageBackground';
import Image from '../../Assets/Images/constant';

const Home = () => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let newValue = value + 1
    setValue(newValue)
  2000)
  [])
  console.log("::::value", value)

  return (
      <React.Fragment>

        <CustomImageBackground backgroundImage={Image.loginBg}
  title={"Home"}
  headerImage={Image.loginBg}
        >
          {/* <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text style={{ color: "#fff" }}>Hello</Text>
          </View> */}
        </CustomImageBackground>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you wanna update a state value with own value it’s better to use a callback

   ```
   setValue(()=> newValue+1)
   ```
2. Add missing comma, currently it‘s not the second parameter which will cause that useEffect will be executed infinitely

```
    useEffect(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        let newValue = value + 1
        setValue(newValue)
      2000), // <<- missing comma
    [])
```

Comment: `setValue(()=> newValue+1)` should really be `setValue((oldValue)=> oldValue+1)`

Comment: there is no use of state is just use it to make the component rerender again and again . i m hopping you are able to see the CustomImageBackground when the state change in home component then CustomImageBackground  get rerender again and again i just want to know how to stop the child rerendring , the useEffect is just for update the state and make home component rerender.